# Generate predefined length string from an alphabet in JAVA

Tags: java, string, algorithm, optimization, cryptography

I trying to create for a school project a brute force method in JAVA that will generate random keys and it will try to decrypt a String.
My approach is to have a String as an alphabet and to define the length so in pseudo-code

```
final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

List<String> getPossibleKeys(String alphabet, Integer keyLength){
...
}

void decrypt(Integer keyLength, String encryptedText){

List<String> keysArray = getPossibleKeys(alphabet, keyLength);

  for(String key: keysArray){
  out.print(doDecryption(encryptedText,key));
}

}
```

My problem is that I do not how how to approach the getPossibleKeys method.

For example lets say the key is "MARIA"so it is of length 5.
I want to be able to call **getPossibleKeys(alphabet, keyLength)** and have an output of

MFTER

PWYTS

GFTGB

...

MARIA

...

FENDF

YJVGN

CVBCV

In other words ALL the possible combinations with EXACT length 5 comming from the alphabet provided.

The examples I have found use all the letters of the alphabet so I could use them and keep only the length I want but I guess there is a better way than that.

Comment: Your approach to generate all possible combinations only works as long as the password length is small. For longer passwords generating the password list may take a long time and consume a lot of RAM. Therefore it is better to incrementally generate only the next password. You could for example use a `char[]` and just increment one element at position x in the array `array[x]` and if it is larger than `'Z'` reset it to `'A'` and increment `array[x+1]` element.

Comment: I understand that it only works for small passwords, thus it is the scope of the assignment, I am not sure I understand how to do what you describe

Answer (score 0):

You really should not want to generate all the keys in one go, as that would create a huge table, which may not even fit into memory. It's amazing how fast you could run out of memory that way.

A better and more appropriate way is to map an integer to each password. Once you have done that you can simply loop over all integers up to the maximum size, and then call a the mapping function.

For passwords (keys are commonly binary), each password consists of letters of the alphabet at each location. So you can create an index of zero to 26^5 for a 5 letter password (assuming your alphabet also contains a `J` ;) ).

So how do you get to create the passwords? Well, that's easier than you might think. Note that computers are binary, and that we calculate in decimals. So the computer is already able to convert from base 2 to base 10. Similarly you can also convert to base 26. This is called "base conversion" and happens what you call e.g. [`Long.toString(long i, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString-long-int-).

The way to perform base conversion is to simply divide a value by the size of the alphabet, and to use the remainder as index into the alphabet, repeating the process for each character. Of course, in Java the divide and remainder are separate operations (in `BigInteger` there is a single function because that's more efficient, but for such small numbers that's not a problem).

```
public static String createPassword(int size, String alphabet, long value) {
    int n = alphabet.length();        
    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(size);
    long changingValue = value; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int charIndex = (int) (changingValue % n); 
        char charInAlphabet = alphabet.charAt(charIndex);
        password.append(charInAlphabet);
        changingValue /= n;
    }
    return password.toString();
}
```

I'll leave it to you to calculate the maximum size given above calculation. If you perform the log_2 over the maximum size then you have the security level in bits that the password provides (somewhat over 23 bits, which should be easy to brute force).

Comment: For fun, use the alphabet `"0123456789"` and then reverse the password after generating it (`StringBuilder` has a function for that). What will be returned?

Answer (score 0):

The resulting list can be generated using recursive approach where each string item is formed from a prefix until the length is achieved:

```java
static List<String> getPossibleKeys(alphabet, keyLength) {
    return getPossibleKeys(alphabet, new ArrayList<>, "", keyLength);
}

private static List<String> getPossibleKeys(
    String alphabet, List<String> acc, String prefix, int keyLength
) {
    if (keyLength == 0) {
        acc.add(prefix); // key is ready, add to the result
    } else {
        for (char c : alphabet.toCharArray()) {
            getPossibleKeys(alphabet, acc, prefix + c, keyLength - 1);
        }
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Test (for a shorter alphabet and length):

```java
System.out.println(getPossibleKeys("ABC", 2));
System.out.println(buildK("AB", 3));
```

Output:

```
[AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC]
[AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA, BAB, BBA, BBB]
```

---

Similar iterative solution resembling the answer by Maarten Bodewes:

- the number of possible keys is *N*<sup>*K*</sup>, where *N* - the length of the alphabet, *K* is the length of the key
- each numeric value is converted into a string using a char array where digits are replaced by the characters at appropriate index of the input alphabet:

```java
static List<String> getPossibleKeys(String abc, int len) {
    int sz = abc.length();
    int num = (int) Math.pow(sz, len);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] key = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j = len, n = i; j-- > 0; ) {
            key[j] = abc.charAt(n % sz);
            n /= sz;
        }
        result.add(new String(key));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

```java
System.out.println(getPossibleKeys("KLMN", 2));
// -> [KK, KL, KM, KN, LK, LL, LM, LN, MK, ML, MM, MN, NK, NL, NM, NN]
```